# SQLITE (fmdb) select where x is null not working

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb, isnull

I'm using FMDB on iOS, attempting to query a table with a statement such as,

```
select * from test where foo isNull
```

In the sqlite C API, this ends up binding to null using this API,

```
int sqlite3_bind_null(sqlite3_stmt*, int);
```

This isn't working. The select invoked through fmdb which seems to be correctly binding the column to null is not finding matching records.

If in the sqlite3 command line session I do the following command, it works, but not through the sqlite C API via FMDB.

```
select * from test where foo isNull;
```

Here's fmdb code which reproduces the problem. It looks like fmdb is doing the proper steps invoking sqlite3_bind_null.

```
        NSString *stmt = @"select * from test where shipToCode=:foo";
        NSDictionary *dict = @{@"foo" : [NSNull null]};
        FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:stmt withParameterDictionary:dict];
        int count = 0;
        while ([rs next]) {
            count++;
        }
        NSLog(@"Count %d", count);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` cannot be compared with the `=` operator; it is not equal with *any* value, even itself.

To compare with `NULL`, you have to use the [`IS NULL`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#collateop) operator:

```
stmt = @"select * from test where shipToCode is null";
```

Comment: I discovered this on my own. Well described.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and check if there are any changes:

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM test WHERE shipToCode is NULL";

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:query];
int count = 0;

while ([rs next]) {
    count++;
}

NSLog(@"Count %d", count);
```